# Why does this for loop not work for the whole list?

Tags: python, for-loop

trying to build my first game for a python course I'm doing.
How would i get this for-loop to iterate through the entire list changing each value to the word 'bull'?
Thank you!

Input:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]

for x in a:
    if x in b:
        b[x] = 'bull'

print (a)
print (b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 'bull', 3, 'bull']
```

Comment: Python is 0-indexed, so you'd have to change your code to `b[x-1] = 'bull'`

Comment: You're using `x` as a value of the list _and_ as an index of the list...

Comment: You've got a bunch of great explanations below, but if all you really wanted to do was change the values in `b` to `"bull"` you don't need the list `a` at all: `b = ['bull' for x in b]` OR `b = ['bull']*len(b)`.

Comment: @pault The end goal was to have that value change to 'bull' if it exists in list A also, not just to change everything to 'bull'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more interesting problem than it first appears.

```
for x in a:
```

will iterate over 1,2,3,4.

```
if x in b:
   b[x] = 'bull'
```

checks if 1,2,3,4, respectively, are in `b`, and sets `b[x]` to `bull`.
Since Python is zero-based indexed, what a simple guess would expect to see is this:

```
b = [1,'bull','bull','bull']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Instead you see this:

```
b = [1, 'bull', 3, 'bull']
```

What gives? And what is zero-based indexing?

Zero-based indexing just means that, if you want the first element of something, you call it at index 0. In other words, if `a = [1,2,3,4]`, then `a[1]` gives `2`, and `a[0]` gives `1`. Confusing, and there are debates among some computer scientists whether this is actually the best way to do it. Some languages, like Fortran and Julia, have one-based indexing, so something like what you're trying to do would actually work there.

Now back to the problem: let's go loop-by-loop.

On your first loop, `x = 1`, so `x in b` evaluates to `True` and `b[1] = 'bull'` evaluates to: `b = [1,'bull',3,4]`.

On your second loop, `x = 2`, *but* `x in b` evaluates to *False*! Remember that `b = [1,'bull',3,4]`, so there's no longer a 2 in `b`, and it skips element assignment!

On the third loop, `3 in b` is `True`, so now `b[3] = 'bull'` and `b = [1,'bull',3,'bull']`.

On the fourth loop, there is no 4 in `b`, so nothing happens.

---

For what you're trying to accomplish instead, you can approach this in one of two ways:

```
for (i,x) in enumerate(a):
    if x in b:
        b[i] = 'bull'
```

In this method, `i` is initialized at 0, and increased by one each loop. So `i` will span: `0,1,2,3`. Perfect for zero-based indexing!

Another approach is to do this:

```
for x in a:
    if x in b:
        b[x-1] = 'bull'
```

When `x` is 1, `x-1` gives you `0`, and remember that `b[0] = 1`.

Comment: great explanation!  one last little tidbit:  on loop 0, index 1 is changed to 'bull' ... it was previously 2.  On loop 1, it searches for `2 in b`... there's no 2 now because 2 was replaced by `bull`!  on loop 2, b[3] (which is 4) is changed to bull.  Thus on loop 3, it searches for `4` in `b`... but `4` was replace by `bull`.  Thus the results:
loop0: `[1, "bull", 2, 3]`
loop1: `[1, "bull", 2, 3]`
loop2: `[1, "bull", 2, "bull"]`
loop3: `[1, "bull", 2, "bull"]`

Comment: You beat me to it! Adding it in now.

Comment: Thank you this really cleared it up for me and help me understand it!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to check if elements at corresponding index of two lists are same.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if x == y:
        b[x-1] = 'bull'

print (a)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print (b)  # ['bull', 'bull', 'bull', 'bull']
```

**Note**: List indices start from `0`. So, you need to assign `bull` to index `x-1` of `b`.

Lastly if you need a **1-liner**:

```
b = ['bull' if x == y else y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is `1`, then `b[x] = 'bull'` will write to `x[1]`, but the position of `1` in the `a` list is actually `a[0]`.

What you want is to use the *indexes* of the values of `a` to manipulate the corresponding values in `b`:

```
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    if b[index] == value:
        b[index] = 'bull'
```

If you actually want to replace the value in `b`, regardless of its index, you need to find the index to manipulate first:

```
for value in a:
    try:
        index = b.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    b[index] = 'bull'
```

Or, even shorter, use a list comprehension:

```
b = ['bull' if x in a else x for x in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below basic code.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c=[]
c=b
i=0
for x in a:
    print (x)
    if x in c:
        c[i] = 'bull'
        i=i+1

print (a)
print (c)
```